# How to animate things before scrolling to another section?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

The case is pretty simple: There is a website with several sections. So on each scrolling, another section appears.

Now some sections may have a textblock, which should fly in animated.

If there is **no** animated textblock, it should have the normal behaviour of scrolling down:

1. st scroll should just scroll down to the next section.

If there is an animated textblock, the scrolling should be in this order:

1. st scroll should animate the textblock; also stay in current section
2. nd scroll then scrolls down to the next section.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks on cancelling scroll

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        //it won't scroll if the destination is the 3rd section
        if(nextIndex == 3){
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

You can change the `onLeave` callback with parameters or methods that determine whether the flying text exists and then continue to the next section, or the flying text needs to fly in and cancel going to the next section.

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I added a check for `hasClass()` to let scroll after that. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Besides using callbacks as named by @dieend, which is the best way to deal with javascript animations and actions, you can also use the state classes added by fullpage.js such as the `active` class added to the active section or the `fp-viwing-x-y` added to the body.

This way you can deal with your animations with CSS alone.

You have a list of state classes [on the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs)

And here [a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M) about how to use the class added to the body to create animations.